# Using an android smartphone as a development platform

Tags: android, arm, usb

Right now I can write programs for my ARM device using my PC and Atmel Studio7.
My PC downloads to the ARM device using USB.
I would like to replace my PC with an Android smartphone.

Can I run GCC on an Android smartphone? (or some other compiler that targets an ARM processor)

Can I use something like AVR Dude to download the executable from the smartphone to my target using USB on the go?

Comment: There are no fundamental limits. Does `mbed` fit your requirements?